# EF6 CodeFirst Ubercontext DB Creation with use of multipe DBContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I have an issue with Entity Framework 6. I try to create my huge DB (CodeFirst) (50+ tables) with a single "ubercontext" and then work with different dbcontext for different concerns.

This UberContext contains:

```
    public class UberDbContext :DBContent
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<UberDbContext >((new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<UberDbContext>()));
            public UberDbContext()
                : base("name=myDb")
            {
                this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            }
    public DbSet<MyEntity1> MyEntity1 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
                const string schemaName = "mySchema";
    ...//all my different entities
                modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity1>().ToTable("MyEntity1", schemaName);
    ...//all my other tables
                modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyEntity1Map());
    ...//all my other entitymaps
    }
```

This works fine, the DB is created when I first use this UberContext. All the Keys and constrains are created with the FluentApi. 
I just have to push it with an        `UberContext.MyEntity1.Add(myDummyEntity1)`
But if I use my other Context which just needs a part of the Db, the code throws a

> ModelValidationException 'MyEntity1' has no key defined. Define the
>   key for this EntityType.

But this should be configurated via the fluentapi. If I add the Key Attribute this works fine but then the constrains cannot be resolved.
It seems that the configuration is ignored.

I searched for this problem the last two days and found nothing.
The idea with the ubercontext comes from Julie Lerman according to her book "DBContext" and this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx

My other Context looks like this:

```
public partial class MyEntity1DbContext:BaseContext<MyEntity1DbContext>
{
public DbSet<MyEntity1> MyEntity1 {get;set;} 
//...
}
```

and BaseContext:

```
public class BaseContext<TContext> : DbContext
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    static BaseContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(null);
    }

    protected BaseContext()
        : base("name=myDb")
    {

    }
}
```

I don't know what to do anymore. I can't change the DB and I don't want all the tables in just 1 DbContext. I think it should be possible or else Julie wouldn't write about it. And it should not be that difficult.
Help would be appreciated. 
Cheers
Oliver

Comment: Do you still need the UberContext in EF6? Isn't this issue addressed in EF6 by "multi-tenant migrations"?  https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multi-tenant%20Migrations.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that. With Migration I understood something else. I would never haver expected to search for the solution there! I read the article http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/digging-in-to-multi-tenant-migrations-with-ef6-alpha/ and try to apply it. This should really be the solution. thanks!

Comment: Be careful tho'. I have not tried what you are doing and really I was asking the question if you need the UberContext in EF6 from the standpoint that I don't really know either. Based on the conversation over here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18882008/150342 I think you probably do.