# Entity Framework, Code First and One-to-Many relationship across multiple contexts

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using VS 2010 and Entity Framework code first (version 6). I have two entities each in its own context and I want to create a one-to-many relationship between them.

Context 1 has the following entity:

```
public class MyTrust
{
    public int MyTrustID { get; set; }
    public string MyTrustName { get; set; }
}
```

and Context 2 has the following entity:

```
public class MyLocation
{
    public int MyLocationID { get; set; }
    public int MyTrustID { get; set; }
    public virtual MyTrust MyTrust { get; set; }
}
```

with the following Fluent API

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyLocation>()
    .HasRequired(m => m.MyTrust);
```

The migration file for Context 2 contains the correct keys but also creates a new table for `MyTrust` which already exists in the other context.

I know that I can edit the migration file but that is not a solution.

My question is, how to I stop the creation of the second `MyTrust` table.

**UPDATE**

There was a major flaw above in that I pasted the wrong code into Context 2. Now corrected. Apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are working with so-called *bounded contexts*. The benefit of such contexts and how to work with them is explained in this [blog by Julie Lerman](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx).

The problem you experience, none of the contexts can be used in migrations, is addressed in this part:

> If you’re doing new development and you want to let Code First create or migrate your database based on your classes, you’ll need to create an “uber-model” using a DbContext that includes all of the classes and relationships needed to build a complete model that represents the database.

Note that you can share the `MyTrust` type between all contexts, if you observe these rules (from Lerman & Miller's book *DbContext*, p 233):

> - An entity can only be attached to one context at a time. This architecture works
>     best with short-lived contexts where the instance to be shared will be completely
>     disassociated from one context before it is attached to another.
> - Entities that are attached to different contexts cannot be attached to one another.

**UPDATE**

In EF6 you can use multiple contexts for one migration path. See [this walkthrough](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/entityframework/2VOa140214-Entity-Framework-6-Code-First-Migrations-with-Multiple-Data-Contexts.html).

Comment: Thanks Gert. There was a major error in the question - now corrected. Does that affect your answer?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You'll always need this "uber context" for migrations. All contexts will still contain the `MyTrust` type, so the sharing part still applies. Context2 has to contain it otherwise you can't define the association.

Comment: @GertArnold doesn't EF6 address this issue in another way that means you don't need the ubercontext? https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multi-tenant%20Migrations

Comment: @Colin This is about having different models in different database schemas. But here at least one entity is shared between contexts, so it is in the same schema. AFAIK, EF has no support (nor any plans) for "merging" contexts into one database schema.

Comment: @GertArnold Gert - thanks for all your help and clarification. Can I please ask a supplementary. Is it possible to create a foreign key across entities in different project, and hence different databases? Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSmith: did you ever find the answer to your question?

Comment: I think that the main answer is that if you are using code first then there is no way to have multiple entities in the same project. In can be done in database first. As regards foreign keys they cannot be shared across databases at any level.

Comment: The linked MSDN article is fantastic.