# Relationships across EF6 Multi-tenant contexts

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to use IdentityDbContext for my security in my mvc5 application.  My application's datacontext should have relationships to my subclass of IdentityUser in IdentityDbContext.  When I try to create these relationships (many-to-many: a MyIdentityUser has many Foo's and a Foo has many MyIdentityUser's), I get 'no key define' errors:
`MyNamespace.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.`

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869068/entity-framework-code-first-and-one-to-many-relationship-across-multiple-contex) seems to indicate that I am going about it the wrong way and should instead create a single context that has everything in it.  My question is this: What's the correct approach to have a single database host the MVC5 security types (so I can use UserManager, Authorize attributes, etc.) along with the rest of my application data?

Should I just subclass IdentityDbContext for my 'uber-model'?  Try to re-create the entities and mappings in IdentityDbContext?  Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Create the two following classes

```
public class IdentityUserLoginConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserLogin>
{

    public IdentityUserLoginConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(iul => iul.UserId);
    }

}

public class IdentityUserRoleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserRole>
{

    public IdentityUserRoleConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(iur => iur.RoleId);
    }

}
```

In the OnModelCreating method within your Applications DbContext add the two configurations outlined above to the model:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IdentityUserLoginConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IdentityUserRoleConfiguration());

    }
```

This should now get rid of the error methods when your model is being created.  It did for me.