# Entity Framework: referencing entities from a model of another context

Tags: entity-framework

I have two Db contexts: CustomersDb which maps to a Customers database, and OrdersDb, which maps to Orders database.
I have a model for each context

```
Customer
{
  Id,
  Name
}

Order
{
  Id,
  Virtual Customer
}
```

How how do I reference the Customer entity from the Orders model correctly? When I seed these DBs, EF creates a Customers table in the Orders database, and obviously, I don't want that

Comment: See Gert's answer on bounded contexts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869068/entity-framework-code-first-and-one-to-many-relationship-across-multiple-contex).

Comment: Are Customer and Order actually in two different databases?

Comment: @GertArnold yes sir

Comment: We need to see the contexts and the entity classes. It looks like you should ignore types in contexts. Hard to tell.

Comment: Try to add `[NotMapped]` attribute to `Customer` property.